# MongoDB 2.4 not allow to create collection after fileSize~=2GB but dataSize~1MB

Tags: mongodb, mmap

I am using MongoDB 2.4 32 bit on ARM processor. I am creating dynamic collections in my database. I went through the MongoDB documentation that states - Storage engine MMAP pre allocates disk space upto 2GB for file system. [32-bit MongoDB processes are limited to about 2 gb of data](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/32-bit-limitations?_ga=1.251506692.345673648.1468810473)

Here is the output of db.stats()

```
{ 
    "db" : "admin", 
    "collections" : NumberInt(40), 
    "objects" : NumberInt(998), 
    "avgObjSize" : 196.9498997995992, 
    "dataSize" : NumberInt(196556), #~1MB
    "storageSize" : 1478905856.0, 
    "numExtents" : NumberInt(42), 
    "indexes" : NumberInt(50), 
    "indexSize" : NumberInt(433328), 
    "fileSize" : 2197028864.0, #2GB
    "nsSizeMB" : NumberInt(16), 
    "dataFileVersion" : {
    "major" : NumberInt(4), 
    "minor" : NumberInt(5)
    }, 
    "ok" : 1.0
}
```

Here as you can see the datasize is 1MB but the filesize is ~=2GB. After the 2GB  file size limit is reached it does not allow me to create new collections.

```
du -sh /data/db
2.1G    /data/db/
```

When I try to repair the database with --repairpath option still it gives the error

```
mongod --repair --repairpath /data/db2
```

Error

```
[initandlisten] ERROR:   mmap() failed for /data/db/admin.7 len:536608768 errno:12 Cannot allocate memory
[initandlisten] ERROR: mmap failed with out of memory. You are using a 32-bit build and probably need to upgrade to 64

[initandlisten] ERROR:   mmap() failed for /data/db2/_tmp_repairDatabase_0/admin.2 len:134217728 errno:12 Cannot allocate memory
[initandlisten] ERROR: mmap failed with out of memory. You are using a 32-bit build and probably need to upgrade to 64
[initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 10084 can't map file memory - mongo requires 64 bit build for larger datasets, terminating
dbexit:
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this issue,

Comment: Are you using the smallfiles option? (https://docs.mongodb.com/v2.4/reference/configuration-options/#smallfiles)?

Comment: No. I do not specify any smallfiles option so I guess default should be false.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the root cause of this problem where fileSize is ~=2GB and dataSize is few MBs and its solution.

**Rootcause** -
If the database uses capped collection, Mongodb 2.4 MMAP storage engine allocates a fixed amount of disk space for these capped collection. Any attempt to create new collections after the datafile size is reached will cause Mongodb 2.4 to throws error.

```
cant map file memory-mongo requires 64 bit build for larger datasets
```

In my case I was creating capped collections dynamically.

**Solution** -
Any operations using `mongod` command to repair database will fail as it requires additional memory to perform these operations.
So use `mongodump` to get the database dump along with `--repair` which will create a dump without "capped" limit for all capped collections and then `mongorestore` it

Step 1 - [Take the dump of database alongwith --repair](https://docs.mongodb.com/v2.4/reference/program/mongodump/)

```
mongodump --username <username> --password <password> --dbpath <path> --db <db> --out <path> --repair
```

Step 2 - [Drop database](https://docs.mongodb.com/v2.4/reference/method/db.dropDatabase/)

```
db.dropDatabase()
```

Step 3 - [Restore the dump](https://docs.mongodb.com/v2.4/reference/program/mongorestore/index.html)

```
mongorestore --username <username> --password <password> --dbpath <path> --db <db> <path>
```

Step 4 - [Convert a Collection to Capped(Optional)](https://docs.mongodb.com/v2.4/core/capped-collections/)

```
db.runCommand({"convertToCapped": "mycoll", size: 100000});
```

Hope this helps.

Cheers